# Huan, the Hound of Valinor, was permitted to speak only three times - why?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

The great hound of Valinor, Huan, had many talents outside what is typical of hounds, one of which is speech. However, Huan was not allowed to just speak freely but instead was only able to speak thrice before he died.

> ... and Huan understood all that was said. For he comprehended the speech of all things with voice; **but it was permitted to him thrice only ere his death to speak with words**.
>
> *The Silmarillion, Of Beren and Lúthien*

As far as I can tell, there is no explanation for this limitation on Huan's ability to speak.

My understanding is that in Tolkien's mythology magical ability and power tends to diminish incrementally over time and after use until the once powerful beings are simply no longer as powerful as they were in the past and can no longer do the same awesome acts (be it creating mountains, taking a physical form, building giant and impenetrable towers, etc.). To me, the fact that Huan is given a finite number of times to perform this magical activity is out-of-place in Tolkien's mythology.

- Is my reading correct that the Valar (or Eru) gave Huan the ability to only speak no more than three times? If so, why? I would be particularly interested in an out-of-universe reason as to why Tolkien chose to make this (as far as I can tell) unusual choice of giving Huan a specific number of occasions to speak, though an in-universe would be interesting as well.
- Or, am I reading this incorrectly and this was actually intended to be a prophesy (or doom) wherein when Huan speaks for the third time his death will soon follow (e.g. Huan was technically able to speak as much as he wanted but a prophesy indicated once he got to three he would have no more opportunity)?

Comment: Three is a magical number in mythology, like seven and nine. Tolkien liked to use these magical numbers, as in "Three rings for the Elven Kings", etc. Why he used it in this particular case, I don't know (and possibly no-one does), but it lends a mythological feel to the story, like a genie only granting three wishes.

Comment: The more often he can talk, the less important any given sentence of his is.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen I completely agree. I guess I was wondering why it wasn’t done more often, like Sauron could only take or change physical form 7 times, or Morgoth could only create 9 dragons, etc. The fact that this device was done only once struck me as odd.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen  Stories of genies granting wishes do not exactly seem mythological to me, more like fantasy fiction.  In any case, the idea that a genie had to grant three wishes seems to a modern idea, see:https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/203836/origin-of-genies-from-lamps-having-a-three-wish-limit/203844#203844

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean that he was given a ration of three times to begin with, and then he used it up. It may be that on a particular occasion, he was given permission to speak once, and this happened to occur two more times, and at some time afterward he died, before such an occasion had arisen a fourth time.

Comment: In the book "A Tolkien Bestiary" by David Day https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7345.A_Tolkien_Bestiary , it says "By decree of the Valar, Huan spoke only three times with words", but doesn't give any more detail about why it had been decreed. (And apparently the author is not considered a reliable source by other Tolkien groups, so this may just be his reading of it).

Comment: @Brian, you can practically ignore anything from David Day. The number of mistakes he makes repeatedly in all of his works are just horrendous. He's about as reliable as anybody's pet parrot.

Comment: I've been thinking about this question, and an answer for it a lot. I believe I have an answer for your second bullet point but based on your comment you've left me a little confused as to what you actually want answered. Is your question specific to Huan, or are you wondering why there aren't more cases like Huan's?

Comment: @Edlothiad For me, and answer specific to Huan will likely inform why there are not more cases like Huan. I was more trying to indicate why Huan’s case was so out of place for me by highlighting the other example where we *don’t* see it.

Comment: @Edlothiad No matter how you would choose to answer I'm sure I would learn more than I currently know now :)

Comment: Sorry for not answering yet, I realise it's been quite a long time since I asked for a clarification. I have to content I want to write up I'm just needing the time to write it up. Hopefully today!

Comment: I think it's that speaking is the province of the Children of Illuvatar (and later dwarves, ents, etc.) and it is usually not allowed to other creatures. Or, to put it differently, dogs are not of the speaking-peoples.

Comment: It’s like Kurt Russell’s per-word fee in _Soldier_. He _could_ have spoken more words, but then he wouldn’t have set the Hollywood record of $40,000 per word.

Comment: @Edlothiad still no time?

Comment: @HahemLovesYou: Tolkien seems to have decided Huan was one of the Maiar, so both his limitation on speaking and his doom to die at the fangs of Draugluin are perhaps punishments for joining the Noldor in their rebellion.

Comment: @Shamshiel where is that written?

Comment: @HahemLovesYou: HoME, Morgoth's Ring,  in Myths Transformed, his latest writing on the subject: *Living things in Aman. As the Valar would robe themselves like the Children, many of the Maiar robed themselves like other lesser living things, as trees, flowers, beasts. (Huan.)*

Comment: @Shamshiel wow I didn't know that thanks for sharing

Answer (score 7):

According to the frequently-reliable [Tolkiengateway, regarding Huan](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Huan_the_Hound), there were separately one grant, and one prophecy, but they were about different things:

The grant:

> Huan had been granted special powers by the Valar, he was as large as a small horse, immortal, tireless and sleepless, **and was allowed to speak three times before he died**.

The prophecy:

> It was also prophesied that he **could not be killed unless it was by the greatest wolf that ever lived**; in this case a werewolf.

Sauron imagined himself to be just that, because he obviously must be The Greatest In All Ways. He wasn't. That was a separate matter, which [Carcharoth](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Carcharoth) politely took care of when the time came. Prophecy fulfilled.

To speak three times was a grant.

**Edited to add** 15 October 2021:

I am copying my answer from the comments, in response to OP SethMMorton's question asking if there are other instances of Tolkien specifying the mystic number three, because even if not out-of-universe, as OP says they may shed light on the question:

Here are some examples of the number 3 in Tolkien. There are 3 Silmarils, 3 types of Hobbit, 3 houses of Edain, the 3 hunters, 3 times Bilbo braves the secret passage ("third time pays for all" he says), 3 peaks of Thangorodrim, and 3 unions of Elves and Men. There are three children of Hurin, there were three Themes in the Great Music, and LotR is set in the Third Age.

Comment: I believe the question is "but why *three* times?"  (As opposed to any other number.)

Comment: @DavidW You make a good point. I don't know, as OP asked, out-of-universe why the number of times granted was precisely three, other than 3 being a mystic number Tolkien frequently used, and that it was the right number to suit the narrative. All I've established in my answer is it was a grant, not a prophecy.

Comment: "3 being a mystic number Tolkien frequently used" - can you expand on that? Besides the 3 Elven rings are there other examples of Tolkien favoring 3? I imagine going down that road may illuminate things.

Comment: @SethMMorton Sure, here are some examples of the number 3 in Tolkien. There are 3 silmarils, 3 types of hobbit, 3 houses of Edain, the 3 hunters, 3 times Bilbo braves the secret passage ("third time pays for all" he says), 3 peaks of Thangorodrim, and 3 unions of Elves and Men. There are three children of Hurin, there were three themes in the Great Music, and LotR is set in the Third Age.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any explanation that Tolkien gave for why Huan was limited to speaking on only three occasions, neither in-universe nor outside. I do agree that it is a little unusual for his work.  Some of the medieval romances feature this sort of arbitrary limit, and they seem to have been among the models for the story "Beren and Luthien", so it is possible that this feature came from such a source, but that is pure speculation.

The late comment suggesting that Huan was in fact a Maia is apparently very little developed. I gather that Tolkien sometimes jotted down ideas in this brief fashion.  Sometimes he later developed them at length, sometimes he later explicitly rejected them, and sometimes he did neither.  Unless there were additional, more developed mentions of this that I have missed (which is surely possible) I would not call this clearly canon. Other Maiar were embodied as men or elves, including Melian (wife of Thingol and mother of Luthien), and Gandalf and the other wizards, so there seems to have been no rule against doing so. Melian  was even able to have children with an elf, and is an ancestress of both Elrond and Aragon.

And of course there are beings of unexplained origin, such as Tom Bombadil, who seems neither an ordinary Man nor a Maia.  Where did Beorn's ability to change to bear-form come from? We are never told, AFAIK.

Te limit does add significance to each speech by Human, and perhaps that was the only reason.